# Method to get the sum of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I am getting the totals of various String ArrayLists such as [1,3,4]...
by parsing them into integers and getting the total. This worked when I coded each individual one, but when I made a method by passing in the total int value and arraylist I always get a value of zero.

A method would save a lot of time.

```
public class Playing {
  static ArrayList<String> list;
  static int Vigor;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     list = new ArrayList<String>();           
      vigoroustotal(list,Vigor);




 public static void Listtotal(String par, int tt) {

    for (String s : par) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        tt += i;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Any changes you do to `tt` inside your method won't be visible anywhere else, because Java passes everything by value. Make the method return an int instead.

Comment: @0x90 There are no pointers in Java. References are also passed by value. If `tt` were a `String` for example, you wouldn't be able to change it either.

Comment: Thats great...But I want to use a running total method for various ArrayLists..This isn't possible?

Comment: @user3156801 Encapsulate that behavior. Create a custom class that holds an `ArrayList` and a `sum`. Any time you add, update the `sum` as well.

Comment: @0x90 - String t = "abc" means (perhaps counterintuitively) that the *reference* t is assigned to that string

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake her is passing the function `tt` and expecting it to be modified.  Java doesn't modify parameters passed to functions.  The corrected code would be this:

```java
public static int ListTotal(List<String> par) {
    int tt = 0;
    for (String s : par) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        tt += i;

    }

    return tt;
}
```

and would be used like this:

```java
Vigor = ListTotal(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

As, said, you need to return the total since java passes everything by-value, so the **int tt** you pass in won't hold a reference to the Vigor variable outside the method.

Therefore, when you pass in primitive types such as (int, char, boolean, byte etc.), anything you do to them inside a method won't be visible outside the method.
However, when you pass in a reference type (Objects such as ArrayList), it is still passed-by-value but that value is a copy of the reference to the Object outside the method. So, in the populateList method bellow, I can just call ArrayList.add() on the input because this input, even though it is passed-by-value, still points to the original Object that was put into this method.

```
public class Playing {
    static ArrayList<String> list;
    static int Vigor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        populateList(list);          
        Vigor = getListTotal(list);
        System.out.println("Total is:\t" + Vigor);
    }

    public static void populateList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        String[] sampleData = { "4", "7", "2" };
        for(int i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i++) {
            list.add(sampleData[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int getListTotal(ArrayList<String> list) {
        int tt = 0;
        for (String s : list) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            tt += i;
        }
        return tt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes that are made to the integer *tt* in the `Listtotal()` method will not be visible anywhere else but that method. You can make that method return an integer to solve that!

```
public static int Listtotal(ArrayList<String> par) {
    int tt = 0;

    for (String s : par) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        tt += i;
    }

    return tt;
}
```

And then you need to change the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();           
    Vigor = Listtotal(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the... let's call it `CountingList`,

```
    public class CountingList {
    private List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    private int sum; 

    public add(String s) { 
        int value = Integer.parseInt(s); 
        integers.add(value); 
        sum += value; 
    }

    private void updateSum() { 
        sum = 0; 
        for (int i : integers) { 
            sum += i; 
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to expose the functionality you need to use outside of the class, but this is (one) way of encapsulating the behavior you're needing.